# display information using the readlink of two files the same

Tags: php, readlink

```
function file_info($name) {
  global $info ;                
    $info[0] = $name ;          // the file name
    $info[1] = filesize($name) ;  // the filesize
    $info[2] = filetype($name);   // the filetype                         
    $info[3] = readlink('/Users/NESSA/Documents/Year2/Operating\ System/Lab4'); 
}
```

Need help in dispalying two of the same files in a directory using readlink. I seem to get a error when using  "$info[3] = readlink('/Users/NESSA/Documents/Year2/Operating\ System/Lab4');". 
The output should be display the link.

Comment: which error did you get ?

Comment: I get 'No such file or directory in ...'

Comment: so your file does not exists

Comment: A copy of the same file exisits under a different name however the code does not show that there is a link under the same directory.